# R force same set of categorical varivables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data set, and trying to force every ID has the same set of categorical variable, this is an example of my current dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c("1","1","1","1",
                "2","2","2",
                "3","3"), 
           group=c("a", "a", "b", "b",
                   "a", "a", "b",
                   "a", "a"),
           flag=c("yes","no","yes","no",
                  "yes","no","yes",
                   "yes","no"),
           value=c(155,789,18,1893,1466,66,4889,1876,33))
```

Current Dataframe:

```
  ID group flag value

1     a  yes   155

1     a   no   789

1     b  yes    18

1     b   no  1893

2     a  yes  1466

2     a   no    66

2     b  yes  4889

3     a  yes  1876

3     a   no    33
```

I would like every ID has the same structure like ID1, total 4 rows, two rows for group a, two rows for group b, and within each group, each have one row for flag yes, another for flag no, and put value to be zero if the row is currently missing. How can I do that? below is the dataframe I want to get.

```
df_toget<-data.frame(ID=c("1","1","1","1",
                    "2","2","2","1",
                    "3","3","3","3"), 
               group=c("a", "a", "b", "b",
                       "a", "a", "b","b",
                       "a", "a","b","b"),
               flag=c("yes","no","yes","no",
                      "yes","no","yes","no",
                      "yes","no","yes","no"),
               value=c(155,789,18,1893,1466,66,4889,0,1876,33,0,0))
```

any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for reading my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete` to do this in one step:

```
df %>%
  complete(ID, group, flag, fill = list(value = 0))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   ID    group flag   value
   <fct> <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
 1 1     a     no     789  
 2 1     a     yes    155  
 3 1     b     no    1893  
 4 1     b     yes     18.0
 5 2     a     no      66.0
 6 2     a     yes   1466  
 7 2     b     no       0  
 8 2     b     yes   4889  
 9 3     a     no      33.0
10 3     a     yes   1876  
11 3     b     no       0  
12 3     b     yes      0
```

Here the first three variables are grouping variables that you want `complete` to fill out missing combinations for, and `fill` is to replace missing values with.